Analog port reading issue in PIC12F510
I am trying simple code on PIC12F510 blink LED using Pot read. LED PIN GP2 and Pot should be GP0.
I am using MPLAB X IDE v 6.20 and compiler 2.36. Just need help read pot value. Based on count value LED_On and LED_OFF.
Timing should be 1000 ms / 3000 ms / 5000 ms / 10000 ms.
#include <xc.h>

// *** Microcontroller MIPs (FCY) *** //
#define FOSC_ 4000000       // * target device system clock frequency: Max Frequency is MHz for 12F510 * //
#define _XTAL_FREQ FOSC_    // * required for __delay_ms, __delay_us macros * //

// CONFIG bits that are part-specific for the PIC 12F510
#pragma config  OSC   = IntRC   // Oscillator Selection bits (internal RC oscillator)
#pragma config  WDT   = OFF     // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config  CP    = OFF     // Code protection bit (CP is OFF)
#pragma config  MCLRE = OFF     // GP3/MCLRE Pin Function Select bit (GP3/MCLRE pin function is GP3)
#pragma config  IOSCFS= OFF     // OFF =  4 MHz INTOSC speed; ON = 8 MHz INTOSC speed

#define LED GPIObits.GP4
#define OFF 0
#define ON 1
#define CALIBRATION_VALUE 0xFCE // Replace 0xXX with the actual calibration value


void SETUP_initialize(void) {
    //OSCCAL = CALIBRATION_VALUE; 
    OSCCAL = 0b11111110;    // Max frequency is set; b-7:1 for calibration bit-0 should be written as 0
    TRISGPIO = 0b00001110;  // '1': for inputs; '0': for outputs (GP1 and GP2 as inputs)
    CM1CON0 = 0b11110110;   // Analog Comparator set OFF
    OPTION = 0b11000111;    // Bit7:RBWU disabled (1), Bit6:RBPU disabled (1)
    LED = OFF;
}

unsigned char ReadAdc(char PinNo) {
    ADCON0 = (0b01110000 | (PinNo << 2)); // Select ADC channel
    ADCON0bits.ADON = 1; // Turn on ADC
    __delay_ms(10); // Wait for ADC to stabilize
    ADCON0bits.GO_nDONE = 1; // Start ADC conversion
    while (ADCON0bits.GO_nDONE); // Wait for conversion to complete
    //return (unsigned char)(ADRES >> 2); // Return 8-bit ADC result
    return ADRES;
}

// Delay functions
void DelayMs(uint16_t time_ms) {
    while (time_ms--) {
        __delay_ms(1);
    }
}

void DelaySec(uint32_t time_sec) {
    while (time_sec--) {
        DelayMs(1000);
    }
}


void main(void) {
    SETUP_initialize();

    for(;;) {
        unsigned char POT_value = ReadAdc(2); // Read ADC value from GP2

        if (POT_value < 25) {
            // Blink 100 ms
            LED = ON;
            DelayMs(10); // 100 ms
            LED = OFF;
            DelayMs(10); // 100 ms
        } else if (POT_value < 50) {
            // Blink 500 ms
            LED = ON;
            DelayMs(50); // 500 ms
            LED = OFF;
            DelayMs(50); // 500 ms
        } else {
            // Blink 1000 ms
            LED = ON;
            DelayMs(1000); // 1000 ms
            LED = OFF;
            DelayMs(1000); // 1000 ms
        }
    }
    return;
}

Build is successful. But not able to read value ADC properly. It always flicker LED at 1 s on and 1 s Off.

You will need to provide details of your circuit as well.

This kind of thing is a bit annoying

DelayMs(10); // 100 ms

and doesn't match this

Timing should be 1000 ms / 3000 ms / 5000 ms / 10000 ms.

Where are you getting the pot comparison numbers from? 25 and 50 are down at one end of the pot rotation, with 128 as half-way, assuming the pot element is connected between GND and Vdd.
Can you stop the processor with a breakpoint in ICD debug mode and view the ADRES value following a conversion?
